# iOS App crash with exception related to _NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, crash-reports

I am currently working on an iOS app which crashes and generates the crash report provided below.We think that the app is crashing due to mutation while Fast Enumeration but the error is occurring in NSISEngine.

We also think that the issue is related to constraints of a Table View. This Table View shows info fetched from Rest Services and we are programmatically updating the DataSource in viewWillAppear().

Some of the constraints we are adding programmatically which are as follows:

```
Method:
```

1.cellForRowAtIndexPath()

Constraints:

```
a. Updated UILabel with attributed String to set line height: 
   [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:self.font range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
   self.attributedText = attributedString;

b. Updated UIImage:
   myCell.myLogo.layer.masksToBounds =YES;
   myCell.myLogo.layer.opaque = NO;
   [[myCell.myLogo layer] setCornerRadius:4.];

c. Border for Table View cell
   mySecondCell.secondCellContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   [mySecondCell.secondCellContainerView.layer setCornerRadius:3.7];
   [mySecondCell.secondCellContainerView addBorderWithColorRed:@214 Green:@214 Blue:@214];
   [myCell.myLogo addBorderWithColorRed:@214 Green:@214 Blue:@214];
```

1. heightForRowAtIndexPath()

Constraints:
    We are calculating height on the basis of the content which is dynamic.

We are using StoryBoard and some of the constraints are set there using Auto Layout.

I searched a lot however was unable to find a crash report similar to the one my app generated. I am new to iOS programming. Can somebody help me with debugging this crash report? If there is a constraint causing this issue, can somebody help me figure out the same? Thanks in advance.

```
    Incident Identifier: F155875B-9FD3-425F-85B9-7595617AF52A
    CrashReporter Key:   aaa79870161ff1e371394b881a26e97f0066f464
    Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
    Process:             myapp [611]
    Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/40D6D77C-1DBB-4F6B-BEE1-73A67C789C49/myapp.app/myapp
    Identifier:          com.myapp
    Version:             1.0 (0.9)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2013-10-17 11:16:45.559 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc9fe86 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x39f9a6c2 objc_exception_throw + 34
    2   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc9f974 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
    3   Foundation                     0x30604f32 -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 438
    4   Foundation                     0x30607ba2 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 334
    5   Foundation                     0x3060594c -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 232
    6   Foundation                     0x3060546e -[NSISEngine optimize] + 170
    7   Foundation                     0x306011a8 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 312
    8   UIKit                          0x32424490 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 292
    9   UIKit                          0x3243114e -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1398
    10  UIKit                          0x32447a9c -[UIView(Hierarchy) insertSubview:atIndex:] + 32
    11  UIKit                          0x325fb888 -[UINavigationBar _wrapView:inClippingViewWithLeftBoundary:rightBoundary:leftMaskImage:leftMaskIsChevron:rightMaskImage:] + 240
    12  UIKit                          0x325b505e -[UINavigationBar _startPopAnimationFromItems:fromBarStyle:toItems:toBarStyle:] + 1982
    13  UIKit                          0x324f1b88 -[UINavigationBar popNavigationItem] + 1316
    14  UIKit                          0x324f14a0 -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransition:] + 556
    15  UIKit                          0x326f02ac ___popViewControllerNormal_block_invoke + 152
    16  UIKit                          0x324d43a0 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
    17  UIKit                          0x324d3fe4 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
    18  UIKit                          0x324d3f78 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
    19  UIKit                          0x3242552e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 342
    20  QuartzCore                     0x320acf3e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
    21  QuartzCore                     0x320a8762 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
    22  QuartzCore                     0x320a85f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
    23  QuartzCore                     0x320a8008 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
    24  QuartzCore                     0x320a7e1a CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
    25  QuartzCore                     0x320d5436 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 158
    26  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5af9b0 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 160
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5af732 _pthread_exit + 82
    28  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b04b8 pthread_exit + 24
    29  Foundation                     0x305d7ac6 +[NSThread exit] + 6
    30  Foundation                     0x30683de0 __NSThread__main__ + 1088
    31  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0c58 _pthread_body + 136
    32  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0bca _pthread_start + 98
    33  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aeccc thread_start + 4


    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x3a572596 szone_free_definite_size + 1510
    1   UIFoundation                   0x3754aab4 -[NSAttributeDictionaryEnumerator dealloc] + 68
    2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x39fa5b06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
    3   libobjc.A.dylib                0x39f9701e (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
    4   QuartzCore                     0x320a1b54 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 64
    5   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc6af6e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
    6   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc688fa __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
    7   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc68c46 __CFRunLoopRun + 734
    8   CoreFoundation                 0x2fbd353c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    9   CoreFoundation                 0x2fbd331e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
    10  GraphicsServices               0x3490a2e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
    11  UIKit                          0x3248a1e0 UIApplicationMain + 1132
    12  myapp                        0x000aac16 main (main.mm:16)
    13  libdyld.dylib                  0x3a493ab4 start + 0

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a537838 kevent64 + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib              0x3a4860d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
    2   libdispatch.dylib              0x3a48063e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

    Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a537a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a53787c mach_msg + 36
    2   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc6a55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
    3   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc68c7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
    4   CoreFoundation                 0x2fbd353c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    5   CoreFoundation                 0x2fbd331e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
    6   Foundation                     0x3060e64c +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316
    7   Foundation                     0x30683dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0c5a _pthread_body + 138
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0bca _pthread_start + 98
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aeccc thread_start + 4

    Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a54a440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
    1   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc6e45e __CFSocketManager + 482
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0c5a _pthread_body + 138
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0bca _pthread_start + 98
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aeccc thread_start + 4
    [12:37:06 PM] Devika Deshmukh: Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a537a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a53787c mach_msg + 36
    2   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc6a55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
    3   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc68c7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
    4   CoreFoundation                 0x2fbd353c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    5   CoreFoundation                 0x2fbd331e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
    6   Foundation                     0x305c1822 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
    7   Foundation                     0x30612664 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
    8   myapp                        0x00197bdc +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:160)
    9   Foundation                     0x30683dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0c5a _pthread_body + 138
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0bca _pthread_start + 98
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aeccc thread_start + 4

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3a4fb09e __abort + 102
    1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3a4fb034 abort + 84
    2   myapp                        0x001bd8ea ___lldb_unnamed_function5196$$myapp + 22
    3   CoreFoundation                 0x2fca018a __handleUncaughtException + 578
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                0x39f9a924 _objc_terminate() + 172
    5   libc++abi.dylib                0x399601b0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
    6   libc++abi.dylib                0x3995fa04 __cxa_throw + 112
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                0x39f9a796 objc_exception_throw + 246
    8   CoreFoundation                 0x2fc9f974 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
    9   Foundation                     0x30604f32 -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 438
    10  Foundation                     0x30607ba2 -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 334
    11  Foundation                     0x3060594c -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 232
    12  Foundation                     0x3060546e -[NSISEngine optimize] + 170
    13  Foundation                     0x306011a8 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 312
    14  UIKit                          0x32424490 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 292
    15  UIKit                          0x3243114e -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1398
    16  UIKit                          0x32447a9c -[UIView(Hierarchy) insertSubview:atIndex:] + 32
    17  UIKit                          0x325fb888 -[UINavigationBar _wrapView:inClippingViewWithLeftBoundary:rightBoundary:leftMaskImage:leftMaskIsChevron:rightMaskImage:] + 240
    18  UIKit                          0x325b505e -[UINavigationBar _startPopAnimationFromItems:fromBarStyle:toItems:toBarStyle:] + 1982
    19  UIKit                          0x324f1b88 -[UINavigationBar popNavigationItem] + 1316
    20  UIKit                          0x324f14a0 -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransition:] + 556
    21  UIKit                          0x326f02ac ___popViewControllerNormal_block_invoke + 152
    22  UIKit                          0x324d43a2 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 870
    23  UIKit                          0x324d3fe4 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
    24  UIKit                          0x324d3f78 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
    25  UIKit                          0x3242552e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 342
    26  QuartzCore                     0x320acf3e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
    27  QuartzCore                     0x320a8762 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
    28  QuartzCore                     0x320a85f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
    29  QuartzCore                     0x320a8008 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
    30  QuartzCore                     0x320a7e1a CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
    31  QuartzCore                     0x320d5436 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 158
    32  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5af9b2 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 162
    33  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5af732 _pthread_exit + 82
    34  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b04b8 pthread_exit + 24
    35  Foundation                     0x305d7ac6 +[NSThread exit] + 6
    36  Foundation                     0x30683de0 __NSThread__main__ + 1088
    37  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0c5a _pthread_body + 138
    38  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5b0bca _pthread_start + 98
    39  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aeccc thread_start + 4

    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a54ac7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aee06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5aecc0 start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x00280a00    r1: 0xfffff000      r2: 0x17f9a000      r3: 0x0000000c
        r4: 0x17f99650    r5: 0x3c32fe08      r6: 0x3c32fe00      r7: 0x27d5cb50
        r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x00000fff     r10: 0x17f99650     r11: 0x0000008a
        ip: 0x17f99db0    sp: 0x27d5cb4c      lr: 0x39f96e39      pc: 0x3a572596
      cpsr: 0x20000030
```

**Update:**

Following is the code by which we are populating our datasource:

```
(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   viewWillAppearFlag = true;
   if(dataFetched) {
       [self setupDatasourceDetails:self.myData];
   }
}


(void) setupDatasourceDetails:(NSArray *)data {
   self.datasource = [MyDatasource new];
   self.datasource.data=data;
   [self.myTable setDataSource:self.datasource];
   [self.myTable setDelegate:self.datasource];
   [self.myTable reloadData];

}

//Callback from REST services
(void) onDataFetched:(NSArray *)data{
   dataFetched=true;
   self.myData=data;
   if(viewWillAppearFlag){
[self setupDatasourceDetails:self.myData]; //the event which will occur later(either viewWillAppear or dataFetched) calls setupDatasourceDetails
 }
}
```

**Update:**

The error is occurring while transition back from one view controller to another (in navigation controller).

We are using [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to transition back to the previous view controller. The transition is happening on the Main thread.

Let us know if any more information is required.

**Update**

It seems that our problem has been resolved. We moved the functionality from viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear. This fix seems to have resolved the issue. Does anyone know the reason why this fix worked? Please let us know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you update your data source? i guess there might be a threading issues with background network fetching

Comment: We have updated the question with relevant code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

1. Check that self.datasource is defined as `strong` property (not
   `weak`) (and the data property on `MyDatasource`)
2. Make sure
   `onDataFetched:`is called on the main queue. If unsure, use this
   dispatching mechanism instead:

   ```
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           // all update code here
      });
   ```

Comment: we followed the dispatching mechanism that you mentioned, in our code. The frequency of the crashes reduced a little but is not eliminated completely. We still are facing the crashes.

Comment: We updated the question with the fix. Thanks for the sugeestion.

Comment: do they still occur if you move it to -viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the error is directly in the code you posted, but:

```
 NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler
```

is raised when you are editing an array or dictionary while enumerating it.
For example this is wrong:

```
for ( id obj in anArray ) {
    if ( [obj shouldRemove == YES ) {
        [anArray removeObject:obj];
    }
}
```

If you need to do that you should work with a copy of an array or use filteredArrayUsingPredicate.

Comment: The answer you are providing is correct. But the Enumeration appears to be happening inside NSISEngine and not directly in our code. That is the reason we are unable to figure out the exact code causing this issue. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Mabye you are editing some view while they are animating back or something ? I see some block invocation - is it on main thread ?

Comment: we are calling [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to navigate back in the NavigationController. Are you talking about its block in the crash report? We are not sure whether it is happening in Main thread. Should that be on main thread? I will check whether it is called on main thread and update my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The transition is happening on main thread. We updated the question with the details. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Can't see all of your code, but I am thinking you need to call layoutIfNeeded before setting the constraints as the views are not calculated before ViewWillAppear. The fact that it succeeds in ViewDidAppear is because the elements have been calculated. Alternately, you could try your code in DidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it would be a fine comment.